# \footnote in \caption within the figure environment gets typeset twice, how to stop that?

Tags: captions, footnotes

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{./foo.png}
            \caption{Blah blah\footnote{something}}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The footnote appears twice this way, but on doing:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{./foo.png}
    \caption{Blah blah}{\footnote{something}}
\end{figure}
```

It appears once but outside the caption.

Comment: by default it would not appear as footnotes within a box can not migrate to the main page.

Comment: Please wrap this in a compilable example that produces the problem as described.  Start the example with `\documentclass` and finish with `\end{document}`. That will give potential helpers an accurate basis for experimenting; making guesses isn't very productive,

Comment: you could possibly use the caption package and `singlelinecheck=off` option but it depends how you have enabled footnotes

Comment: @barbarabeeton edited.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry I don't follow what you're trying to say.

Comment: Your minimal document doesn't show the problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn you need more than a line of blah

Comment: If you provided an example that showed the problem, most likely `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{captipn}` would fix it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You might as well just add this as an answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn OK, done

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, that worked. Does this mean that the caption being more than a single line doesn't get typeset twice?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not provided an example that shows the issue but you can prevent the caption being evaluated twice with

```
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
```

This will mean it is always set in a parbox rather than using a different layout for short captions that fit in one line.